# Editable Table data and updating state in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-table

I rendereed the table as per the input given from the form, my concern is to make the table row editable and on editing , I mean onChange() the name should store in the this.state.

So here is my App.js file,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    names: [
      /*
        Object structure
          {id: 1,name:'Aashiq'}
      */
    ]
  };

  handleNameChange(e) {
    this.setState(
      {
        names: { ...this.state.names, name: e.target.value }
      },
      console.log(this.state.names)
    );
  }

  renderTable() {
    return this.state.names
      .sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
      .map((eachName) => {
        const { id, name } = eachName;
        return (
          <tr key={id}>
            <td>{id}</td>
            <td onChange={(e) => this.handleNameChange(e)}>
              <div contentEditable>{name}</div>{" "}
            </td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="button"
                value="Delete"
                onClick={() => this.deleteName(eachName.id)}
              />
            </td>
          </tr>
        );
      });
  }

  deleteName = (id) => {
    this.state.names &&
      this.setState({
        names: this.state.names.filter((name) => name.id !== id)
      });
  };

  addName = (newName) => {
    this.setState((currentState) => {
      const newNames = [...currentState.names];
      newNames.push(newName);
      return {
        names: newNames
      };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Form onSubmit={this.addName} names={this.state.names} />
        <br />
        <table id="details">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Names</th>
              <th>Operation</th>
            </tr>
            {this.renderTable()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see here ,I've tried to use contentEditable attribute inside the div, but its not reflecting on using any handler functions ,so It will be good some one come up with a solution ,btw I need to edit only the name field.

[image: The Browser output]

Comment: Just put an input within the <td> and handle input as usual.

Comment: How would it tell the user that the content is editable? My suggestion is use a standard input that maybe shows its border on hover, and user can just click and edit if desired then

Comment: You mean enabling and disabling the input field on a button click

Comment: Ya @Chiranjib, i want to have a edit button in the operation column to handle the data, can you give suggestions based on that context?

Comment: Have posted an answer, very crude but should be able to get you going

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [entries, setEntries] = useState([
    { name: "Name 1" },
    { name: "Name 2" }
  ]);
  const [indexToEdit, setIndexToEdit] = useState(-1);
  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>Button</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        {entries.map((entry, recordIdx) => (
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input
                type="text"
                value={entry.name}
                disabled={recordIdx !== indexToEdit}
                onChange={(val) => {
                  let _entries = [...entries];
                  _entries[indexToEdit] = val;
                  setEntries(_entries);
                }}
                onBlur={() => {
                  setIndexToEdit(-1);
                }}
              />
            </td>
            <td>
              <button
                onClick={() => {
                  setIndexToEdit(recordIdx);
                }}
              >
                Edit
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```